# A $C^k$ manifolds ($k>1$) has a $C^\infty$ atlas: reference request

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I remember that there is a theorem saying that "any $C^k (k>1)$ manifold has a smooth atlas" so that, instead of consdering $C^k$ manifolds, we study smooth manifolds.

What is this theorem called and where can I find its proof?

Comment: Does every theorem needs to have name?

Comment: @Creator Definitely not, but I'm having trouble searching for its proof. That's why I asked whether there is a name for this theorem. Actually, I'm not sure whether the statement is correct. I just remember I heard that from someone someday, but I have no idea who it was and what exactly the statement was.

Comment: I think Hirsch has this.

Comment: For a textbook reference (Hirsch), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747752/every-mathcalc1-manifold-can-be-made-smooth?rq=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a result by Hassler Whitney, in one of his earlier papers on manifolds, that any maximal $C^r$ atlas, for $r>0$, contains a $C^\infty$ atlas.  I can't find the specific paper at the moment, but it should be in [volume I](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=qPA6LEjOR4kC&pg=PR10&lpg=PR10&dq=hassler+whitney+papers&source=bl&ots=O7nXJP5CBx&sig=j4NeZCvztZQYYbp6gudUiZTZvwY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2q9rPgsfOAhWCipQKHWEeD04Q6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=hassler%20whitney%20papers&f=false) of his collected publications. My guess would be either [24] or [28] in the bibliography.

Most textbooks I know of, such as Jeffrey Lee's Manifolds and Differential Geometry, mention the result, but don't find it worth proving, so I would suggest looking for Whitney's original paper if you want to see the proof.

Comment: It's reference [28]. See the paper on jstor here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968482?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents.